# Why is for /f pulling up the file name?

Tags: parsing, batch-file, for-loop, filenames

I have a text file named **paths.txt** It contains the following data,

> LocalName  RemotePath
>   N:         \DANIEL-HP\Users\Public
>   Z:         \DANIEL-HP\Users\Public\Favorites
>   LocalName  RemotePath
>   N:         \DANIEL-HP\Users\Public
>   Z:         \DANIEL-HP\Users\Public\Favorites

I am running the following batch file to extract the desired info path letter, path.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('find ":" paths.txt') do (
echo %%a
)
pause
```

The result

```
---------- PATHS.TXT
N:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public
Z:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public\Favorites
N:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public
Z:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public\Favorites
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The way that I fix this is I modify the **FOR** as below,

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('find ":" paths.txt') do (echo %%a)
```

And I get a clean desired output,

```
N:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public
Z:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public\Favorites
N:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public
Z:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public\Favorites
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Question is, what is wrong with my first FOR function that it is allowing the filename to passthrough.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your FIND command, not your FOR /F.

FIND always prints out the name of the file like that if it opens the file itself (if the file name is passed in as an argument).

You can avoid the file name by using redirection:

```
find ":" <paths.txt
```

or a pipe:

```
type paths.txt | find ":"
```

To use these in a FOR loop, the pipe or redirection has to be escaped.

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('find ":" ^< paths.txt') do echo %%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('type paths.txt ^| find ":"') do echo %%a
```

Another alternative is to use FINDSTR instead (but only if the file is ASCII):

```
findstr ":" paths.txt
```

If the file is unicode (UTF-16), then you can convert the content to ASCII by piping the output of the TYPE command (again, escape the pipe if used within FOR /F):

```
type paths.txt | findstr ":"
```

Comment: find ":" <paths.txt and type paths.txt | find ":"    screen just flashes.
findstr ":" paths.txt returns a blank output

Comment: @dbenham....All the solutions you have suggested are working perfectly outside the **for loop** but within the brackets '()' of the for loop, they are not. Pls advice the syntax.

Comment: @DannyBoi The special charaters need to be escaped, see the edit

Comment: I just executed `findstr ":" paths.txt` outside the **for loop** i get,
` N :                   \ \ D A N I E L - H P \ U s e r s \ P u b l i c
 Z :                   \ \ D A N I E L - H P \ U s e r s \ P u b l i c \ F a v o r i t e s`
It is deliberately putting a space before every character.

Comment: @DannyBoi - Your file must be unicode (probably UTF-16), which does not work with FINDSTR. The FINDSTR command only supports ASCII. My answer has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

need to be deleted ;))

/*
i advice:

```
find ":" ^<paths.txt
type paths.txt ^| find ":"
```

findstr working great.. i not understand what the blank you have

```
@echo off
set "tmp=PATHS.TXT"----your value
echo,---findstr
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('findstr ":" %tmp%') do (echo %%a)
echo,---type
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('type %tmp% ^| find ":"') do (echo %%a)
echo,---redirect
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('find ":" ^<%tmp%') do (echo %%a)
```

*/

Comment: `---findstr
---type
N:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public
Z:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public\Favorites
N:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public
Z:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public\Favorites
---redirect
N:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public
Z:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public\Favorites
N:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public
Z:         \\DANIEL-HP\Users\Public\Favorites`
Thats the output i get